# Unable to append data to file using BufferedWriter

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

This is rewriting the whole file.  How do I append contents to existing file "Data.txt"?

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class WriteToFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
        {
            String content = "This is the content to write into file";
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt", true));
            bw.append(content);
            System.out.println("Done");
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I run it n times, I should get n times "This is the content to write into file".  I get only once?

Comment: Then you aren't showing the code you are actually running. The above will currently append the String to the existing contents of the file. Note, it appends it on the same line.

Comment: where do you view the file? maybe you just need to refresh the editor's  buffer. close the file and re-open t.

Comment: Wierd, it is working now.  I forgot to close the stream.
Will bw.close() close all nested streams?

Comment: Yes it will, since all system resources should be released upon a call of this method. If other nested streams were left open then they would be invalid, so there is no point in leaving then open. See the javadoc for [Closeable#close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html#close%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

Although, your code work for me. You can test another way. Wrapped your `BufferedWriter` with `PrintWriter` and run.

```
 String content = "This is the content to write into file";
 PrintWriter out =new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("Data.txt", true)));
 out.append(content);
 out.close();
```